# Custom translation function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I have an application that I'm currently localizing to Arabic but Im facing a small problem.

In the English version of the website, I display some sizes as follows `10x15 15x18` etc, and they are stored in the database as such.

In my Arabic version I want to display instead `10*15 15*18` etc.

Currently, I have a string replace function in one of the models as follows:

```
if I18n.locale == :ar
   size.sub! 'x', '*'
end
```

but I'm sure that I shouldn't have code like that in a model. How can I do this using the usual I18n ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` in database is internal for your storage means, so strictly speaking for english you also should have `size.sub! 'x', 'x'` (which does nothing, because symbol is the same, but it changes it's meaning).

You're correct that symbol belongs to locale. Locales support variables in translations:

```yaml
en:
  some_size: "%{width}x%{height}"
```

```yaml
ar:
  some_size: "%{width}*%{height}"
```

```rb
I18n.t('some_size', width: size.split('x').first, height: size.split('x').second)
```

(to make the last expression more tidy - you can have width/height or size_hash and use splats)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Following the logic of seperating the widh and height fixed the problem for me. I dont understand the first couple of lines though. Why should I use size.sub! in this case?

Comment: @mrateb you should not, it was for example to show reason for separation

Comment: Ok got what you mean. Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation :)